# Pass dictionary inside dictionary to web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have following data coming through our web api

{"ReportDetails":[{"FromDate":"2020-11-10","ToDate":"2020-11-10","EmailIDs":"rpatel@allentowninc.com","RackBlowerDetailsID":"606c9a27-3fde-4100-a962-40cac5c6ac23","RackBlowerCustomerID":"3e669f75-d4f3-46e7-92ab-5f301ffe87e6","AvgData":"","AllData":[{"Mode":"Pos","ACH":"67","CFM":"CFM, 7","Pressure":"-0.025 WC","Blower Name":"Aln","Blower Address":"0.0.0.0","Rack Model":"0JV042","Date":"2020-11-10 00:00:48","Supply Temp":"75 F","Supply Humidity":"36 %","Exhaust Temp":"75 F","Exhaust Humidity":"38 %","RPM -S":"656","RPM -E":"731","AirFlow":"7 CFM","Blower Alarm":"","Hepa Filter Alarm":"","PreFilter Alarm":"X","Hose Alarm":""},{"Blower Name":"Aln","Blower Address":"0.0.0.0","Rack Model":"0JV042","Date":"2020-11-10 00:05:48","ACH":"67","Supply Temp":"75 F","Supply Humidity":"36 %","Exhaust Temp":"75 F","Exhaust Humidity":"38 %","RPM -S":"656","RPM -E":"728","AirFlow":"7 CFM","Pressure":"-0.025 WC","Blower Alarm":"","Hepa Filter Alarm":"","PreFilter Alarm":"X","Hose Alarm":""},{"Blower Name":"Aln","Blower Address":"0.0.0.0","Rack Model":"0JV042","Date":"2020-11-10 00:10:49","ACH":"67","Supply Temp":"75 F","Supply Humidity":"36 %","Exhaust Temp":"75 F","Exhaust Humidity":"38 %","RPM -S":"655","RPM -E":"732","AirFlow":"7 CFM","Pressure":"-0.025 WC","Blower Alarm":"","Hepa Filter Alarm":"","PreFilter aAlarm":"X","Hose Alarm":""}] }]}

We are unable to read dictionary object with key AllData.
all other key is working fine. we get the correct values.
this is what we have in webapi
public JsonResult SendReportEmail(List<Dictionary<String, Object>> ReportDetails)

Not sure what we are doing wrong.
Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that "AllData" is an json array instead of a normal json property.
Maybe this approch helps you:

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

var reportDetails = jObject["ReportDetails"][0];
var fromDate = reportDetails["FromDate"];
var toDate = reportDetails["ToDate"];
var allData = reportDetails["AllData"];
```

Comment: This is what we try to do in webapi.
But we always get allData as system.object

Dictionary<String, Object> dicR = ReportDetails[0];
String FromDate = dataRowToString(dicR, "FromDate");
String ToDate = dataRowToString(dicR, "ToDate");
object val;
string avgData = string.Empty;
string allData = string.Empty;
if (dicR.TryGetValue("AvgData", out val))
{
avgData = val.ToString();
}
if (dicR.TryGetValue("AllData", out val))
{
allData = val.ToString();
}